# JavaFX ChoiceBox ContextMenu shown again when it is displayed and clicked again

Tags: swing, javafx

I have JavaFX panel with ChoiceBox in Swing application. Standard behaviour of ChoiceBox is that when you click it for the first time the popup menu with items is shown and when you click ChoiceBox for the second time, the popup menu is hidden. But when you put it to Swing application the second click causes popup to hide and to be shown immediately again. How can I prevent this behaviour?

```
public class ComboTest {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        ChoiceBox choiceBox = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList("item 1", "item 2"));
        VBox vbox = new VBox(choiceBox);
        return new Scene(vbox);
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that when I click the choicebox for the second time the popup loses focus which causes it to hide and the choicebox then handles mouse click and shows the popup again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this problem caused by the existing `ChoiceBox` [bug in javafx](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175963).
The simplest fix is just to use [`ComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) instead:

```
ComboBox<String> choiceBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("item 1", "item 2"));
```